# Help: This form cannot be opened in a Web browser

Tags: infopath, form, library

I created an InfoPath form (2013) and published to a form library on SharePoint (2010). I added a quick link icon on the homepage to open the form (filler form). This is where I received the error message: "This form cannot be opened in a Web browser. To open this form, use Microsoft InfoPath." If I go to the form library and click "Add document", the form opens fine (InfoPath app) ! The form is not supposed to open in web browser and I've ensured on InfoPath the form type is Filler form.

The icon URL:

```
/Private_bfm/SOW_Form/Forms/template.xsn
```

Comment: Make sure the default opening behavior is the filler both on the InfoPath form and the sharepoint library.

Comment: Confirmed and still receiving the error.